# Aggregate extension for Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I am trying to create a generic Aggregate extension on `Dictionary`. Something like this..

```
void Main(){
    var foo = new Dictionary<string, Metric>();
    foo["first"] = new Metric(5);
    foo["sec"]  = new Metric(10);

    foo.Aggregate<string, Metric, int>("first", new Metric(5));
}

public class Metric : IAggregatable<int> {
    public int Total { get; set; }

    public Metric(int total) {
        Total = total;
    }

    public void Aggregate(int value) {
        Total += value;
    }
}

public static class DictionaryExtensions {
    public static void Aggregate<TKey, TValue, T>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key, TValue value) where TValue : IAggregatable<T> {
        TValue result;
        if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            dic[key].Aggregate(value.Total);
        else
            dic[key] = value;
    }
}

public interface IAggregatable<T> {
    T Total { get; set; }
    void Aggregate(T value);
}
```

This works well but I have to specify the generic type arguments every time I make the call to `Aggregate(...)`. This can be seen in `main()` as `foo.Aggregate<string, Metric, int>("first", new Metric(5));`. Is there a cleaner way to get this functionality because I would prefer to not have to specify the generic type parameters every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interface is a bit clunky. You don't need to know the internals of your metrics. To aggregate, you only need to know *what* can be aggregated, not how. The *how* can be handled by the implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Metric : IAggregatable<Metric>
    {
        public int Total { get; set; }

        public Metric(int total)
        {
            Total = total;
        }

        public void Aggregate(Metric other)
        {
            Total += other.Total;
        }
    }

    public static class DictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static void Aggregate<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key, TValue value) where TValue : IAggregatable<TValue>
        {
            TValue result;
            if (dic.TryGetValue(key, out result))
                dic[key].Aggregate(value);
            else
                dic[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public interface IAggregatable<T>
    {
        void Aggregate(T other);
    }

    class Program
    {
        void Main()
        {
            var foo = new Dictionary<string, Metric>();
            foo["first"] = new Metric(5);
            foo["sec"] = new Metric(10);

            foo.Aggregate("first", new Metric(5));
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `TryGetValue` if you're not going to use the `result`?

Comment: Right it should be `result.Aggregate(value)` after the if statement so that your not doing two lookups thats my bad